# How to put .cs file in app_code and its ascx file out of app_code folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webusercontrol

In a ASP.net website project how to link cs file in app_code with ascx file of a UserControl ?

Comment: What on earth would be the reason to do such a thing? - could you elaborate on exactly what you want to achieve? - I am not exactly sure of what you are looking for.

Comment: The reason is that i have a class file "abc.cs" in app_code folder which is unable to access my custom control's class. Hope you get it.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than putting into `app_code` you should put it into `app_theme` folder.

Here is a MSDN [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx) for the same.